# Design pattern for a model-less web-application

Tags: design-patterns

I'm developing a webapp and I'm not sure which pattern design should I use. In spite of the current trend towards MVC, this is a good choice for applications that deals with a lot of models, CRUD operations, etc. Our application has a different intern structure:

What we do is:

1. Allow user to upload a data file and be redirected to another page.
2. That page will be filled by some informations about that data file.
3. User will have to select some parameters, and click a button.
4. Depending on the button, some action will be performed and the result may be a number or another file to be downloaded.

As you can see, the only model I have is the user that will own a "session". The only table I have on my DB is the 'users' table. All other usability of the application is performed during the session and no data is persisted.

Is there any Design Pattern that fits well my needs? I'm using Java!

Thanks!

Comment: You say no data is persisted, yet files are uploaded and downloaded, files are persistent data are they not?  Further, are you planning to have all the logic hard coded?  Or might you want it to be data driven?  There's more to models than CRUD operations, and it would seem like your entire set of data is very Model oriented.

Comment: The data is not persisted because it's temporary. It's attached to the session, and as soon as the session is destroyed, the temporary directory is also destroyed.
It's not clear to me when you say logic 'hard coded' or 'data-driven'. Could you say more about it?
And I said I believe that MVC isn't the most suitable Design Pattern for my case, because it only have one (or two, if the data file is one) models, it has only two views (form and one that display the parameters), and therefore just one controller. I've heard about Template Pattern, Page Pattern, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: I see no reason at all why not to choose MVC, except personal preference of course. MVC isn't restricted to or more beneficial with multiple models. And whether the data is persistant or not is of no consequence either.

Comment: If you ask me based on your description of the use case, I say MVC is an overkill (unless there is more to the application that what you described). I would say just use a simple Servlet (may be a HttpSessionLisetner) for processing and (html/jquery) for your user inputs that should do it. You could also look at a single page app with java script framework like (Backbone or knockout)

Comment: I understand that model != database. I also understand that MVC is a feasible model (actually it's currently written using the MVC pattern). My point is, as Prasanna said, MVC may be an overkill for a webapp that just have two views, the controller just have to take the user from Home to this page. My webapp can be written using the MVC pattern, but can't benefit from its features. Am I misssing something? I believe Prasanna is leading me to what I'm looking for: that single page app. I'll look for more informations about it. ;)

Comment: To stick to the style: view != page.
:)
It _can_ be obviously, but not necessarily so. I'd guess by your description there are approximately 3 views and at least 2 models. MVC is definitely not overkill. (and wouldn't be even if it were only one view, model and controller)
MVC is just a pattern, instead of cramming everything into 1 class you use 3, what's the overkill? Don't get me wrong you don't HAVE to use MVC, but all of the non-arguments listed here are definitely no reasons not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's important in an application, is not the design pattern used but properly addressing [**separation of concerns**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

MVC is just an example in that direction. It allows you to separate the application data and all the logic that goes with it (Model) from the presentation of that data (View). User's interactions with the View is coordinated by the Controller who also transforms those interactions to actions to be performed by the Model.

A lot of applications fit into this behavior, so MVC is the obvious choice for them. If you think that MVC is overkill, then maybe go for a simplification of it like the [Model Delegate](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelDelegate) (sometimes also referred as the Model/View Pattern). But again, the pattern is not important; what's important is to properly separate the responsibilities within the application.

In your comments you mention that your application is already MVC, so I would leave it at that. I can't see how that's overkill and as your application will grow (and I'm sure it will) you'll be glad it was designed like that from the start.